# Mi aplicación no se conecta con firebase para icloud messaging al configurar mi app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-messaging

tengo un problema he hecho todos los pasos que me dice firebase para poder conectarme  su servidor (quiero hacer notificaciones push) pero cuando me dice que instale mi app para ver si hay conexión lo hago pero nunca se conecta no se donde he fallado,
por si acaso yo he borrado y re he contratado borrado mi app de firebase y recreando me otra para ver si era eso y también descargando nuevos google-services.json obviamente pero nada.

aqui esta mi configuración en module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.loyaltyclubs.sbcclub"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 12
    versionName "2.1.2"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
     optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
}

  dependencies {

 ....
//implementacion firabase

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'

...

}
```

este es mi archivo de proyecto:

```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
    }



  }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

    //DEPENDECIA PARA FIREBASE CLOUDMESSAGIN

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'


  }
 }

 allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

 }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

este es mi archivo google-services.json que me descargue

```
{
  "project_info": {
  "project_number": "694482594413",
  "firebase_url": "https://sbc-club-9c402.firebaseio.com",
  "project_id": "sbc-club-9c402",
  "storage_bucket": "sbc-club-9c402.appspot.com"
},
 "client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": 
   "1:694482594413:android:64ea67ec3153f8beb8ad64",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.loyaltyclubs.sbcclub"
    }
  },
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "694482594413- 
   pdsmpogjof6vie0hsfjem4d4nm9p5bo7.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 3
    }
  ],
  "api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": "AIzaSyCn2XKJAZMGU8JPtf73LCsYaJIJeFS18z0"
    }
  ],
  "services": {
    "appinvite_service": {
      "other_platform_oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "694482594413- 
  pdsmpogjof6vie0hsfjem4d4nm9p5bo7.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
],
   "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Bueno el punto es, cuando se hace todo eso de poner nickname, paquete de proyecto etc, a lo ultimo te pide que instales, y es posible reinstalar etc en ese momento nunca se conecta mi app con el servidor es primera vez q me pasa con otras aplicaciones eso no me paso, no se que me estaría faltando , o será porque borre elimine , borre y elimine etc ? gracias.

[image: Esta es mi configuracion en firebase]

Comment: Tu aplicación tiene configurado el servicio? tienes definido el servico en el AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Sin pero nada amigo.

Answer (score 0):

En tu proyecto debes tener una clase la cual extiende de `FirebaseMessagingService` , esta clase es la que recibe el mensaje dentro del método `onMessageReceived()` :

```
public class FCMMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        String from = message.getFrom();
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
  ...
  ...
}
```

pero esto debe funcionar si la clase es definida como servicio dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <service android:name=".FCMMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

> Un servicio que extienda FirebaseMessagingService. Esto es obligatorio
>   si deseas administrar los mensajes además de recibir notificaciones en
>   apps en segundo plano. Para recibir notificaciones en apps en primer
>   plano, recibir la carga útil de datos y enviar mensajes ascendentes,
>   etc., debes extender este servicio.

Revisa

[**Configura una app cliente de Firebase Cloud Messaging en Android**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=es)

Comment: Holaa muchas gracias por responder, te cuento que hice todo eso y no me funciona :(. inclusive configure con la herramienta de tools->firebase y me dice conectado exitosamente , pero al querer probar con una notificacion desde firebase console no me envia. :(. gracias.